# start systemd service as dependancy on SYSV service

Tags: nfs, systemd, sysv

I have a SYSV service (`rstudio-server`) running on CentOS7. After boot, it happens to run prior to mounting of NFS filesystem, which is required by `rstudio-server` service. How do I specify dependency for `rstudio-server`, which is a SysV service, given that it does not have a unit file? Do I need to create a unit file for the rstudio-server service and then specify "After="?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `Before=rstudio-server.service` in `[Unit]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target` solved the issue.